# Powershell command for extracting all users from a domain

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, powershell, powershell-v3.0

`Get-ADUser -SearchBase "dc=contoso,dc=local" -filter * -properties Name, Surname, samAccountName, Enabled, PasswordNeverExpires, PasswordExpired, PasswordLastSet, MemberOf | Select Name, Surname, SamAccountName, Enabled, PasswordExpired, MemberOf | Export-Csv C:\temp\expired3.csv`

I need a list of all users in the domain with this respective attributes, the problem is with the `MemberOf` attribute. Instead of getting the groups that they are part of I only get `Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Select @{name=”MemberOf”;expression={$_.memberof -join “;”}}` to export the multivalued attribute "MemberOf" to your CSV:

```
Get-ADUser -SearchBase "dc=contoso,dc=local" -filter * -properties Name, Surname, samAccountName, Enabled, PasswordNeverExpires, PasswordExpired, PasswordLastSet, MemberOf | `
        Select Name, Surname, SamAccountName, Enabled, PasswordExpired, @{name=”MemberOf”;expression={$_.memberof -join “;”}} | `
            Export-Csv C:\temp\expired3.csv
```